# Connect to redshift using sagemaker notebook instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to connect to redshift using sagemaker notebook instances. I want to run Unload commands to unload data from redshift to s3 using IAM role and schedule the sagemaker notebook.
I want to know how I can import db credentials in sagemaker without hardcoding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) to store and access credentials. Your Sagemaker execution role should have permission to read from Secrets Manager (AFAIK AWS managed-role does have it). This is the same mechanism that's used by Sagemaker notebooks to get access to github repo, for example